# Fail to upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip over releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)

I tried to upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 by Update manager, but failed.

The error message was:

```
Failed to fetch http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/ttf-alee/ttf-alee_12+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can the person that down voted please add a comment. Thank you.

Comment: @Ants You mustn't add a comment after a down vote. it's optional.

Comment: I think if you add a comment it helps the user to refine their question next time. Simply down voting doesn't let the user know what they've done wrong.

Comment: @SanghyukJung If you say 11.04 and mean 11.10 you really deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 3):

You can't upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04. You must upgrade to 11.10 and then to 12.04. You can only skip upgrades if you upgrade from an LTS (10.04) to a LTS (12.04). You can't skip in-between.

I suggest you download an [11.10 image from here.](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/) And then upgrades via a usb-stick (live-cd). and then [upgrades to 12.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/), via the same method.

Comment: I tried, but got same result.

Comment: @SanghyukJung what did you try? what exactly did you do? :)

Comment: Why fresh install 11.10 only to upgrade?? Just do a fresh install of 12.04.

Comment: @amc it's not a fresh install it's an upgrade via live-cd!

Comment: But i think when you use a live cd you can upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 directly!!
The online upgrade needs 11.10!
Just confirm once...!

Comment: @Nirmik I've never heard that before. Can you confirm it in any way possible?

Comment: Well i dint get any such statment as to it cannot be done but from the ubuntu community update notes it seems you are correct.. :)

Comment: @Alvar I tried online update from 11.10 to 12.04. It was failed yesterday, but it works now. I guess there are temporarily problems in accessing http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/ttf-alee/ttf-alee_12+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I guess there was a temporarily problem in accessing http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/ttf-alee/ttf-alee_12+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb

I downloaded 'ttf-alee_12+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb' from a mirror site and install it manually, then completed  the online update.

But now 'ttf-alee_12+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb' is available on 'kr.archive.ubuntu.com'. I guess there is no problem now.

Thank you for all comments.

Comment: you said it was 11.04 to 12.04, which you can't do. But now you say it was 11.10 to 12.04! it's impossible to help you if you don't give us the correct information.